# Android Local Maven Repository transitive Dependencies

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin

I think this question is maybe asked before but i cant find a solution for my problem.

My project depends on many submodules. I have deployed the libraries with maven to a server in our local network. Now i have a problem, if a library depends on another library e.g retrofit. The dependency is given in the pom.xml file from the library.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit</groupId>
      <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If i build my app the retrofit library isnt loaded and i get a NoClassDefFound exception at runtime.

I have deployed the library as a aar and jar file, but the behaviour wont change.

Any suggestion how to get the dependencies from a maven repository?

**Edit:**
I found out that the problem is, that ivy.xml doesnt contains dependencies. How to declare a dependency for the ivy.xml in the pom.xml?

Comment: [`retrofit`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/1.9.0) is available on Maven Central. I'm not sure what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry if is not clear. I have a local maven repository which depends on retrofit. If a project depends on my library i want that android studio get the retrofit library automatically without declaring this in the build.gradle file. Hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: If your project depends on retrofit, then the POM of this project declares retrofit as dependency. So when you depend on your project, retrofit will be added as transitive dependency automatically (no need to specify it).

Comment: Thats the problem. Retrofit isnt loaded automatically from maven central oder jcenter and then i get a a NoClassDefFound Exception at runtime.